# How can I download Windows 7 DVD installers from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, windows-7, iso

I have rights for a free license of Windows 7, given by my University, and I need it now. According to Microsoft's instructions, to download the Windows DVD image I must:

- download a Secure Download Manager (SDM) installer (its a .pkg file)
- run the .pkg file, which should install the SDM
- download another file (.sdx),
- run the .sdx file, which should start the download of the Windows DVD image.

However, the SDM installer (.pkg) does not run.

The .sdx file, when opened in the text editor, is simply an internet address. When I paste the address in the browser, it goes to the download page, but the download bar remains in 0%. So, I believe I really must install this SDM first.

Any help on this problem? Does someone know how to run this .pkg file?

Comment: I already tried to convert the .pkg file to .deb using alien, but it returns the message:

"Unknown type of package, sdm.pkg".

Also, when I type file sdm.pkg, the terminal returns:

"sdk.pkg: xar archive - version 1".

I dont have any idea of what to do with these information

Answer (score 7):

### Download the official ISOs to get an easily burnable DVD image

- You can *officially* download Windows 7 ISOs over HTTP for the common versions/languages from one of their resellers, DigitalRiver. Digital River sells Windows 7 licenses and makes the ISOs available for public download.
- While all x86/x64 versions of Windows 7 are available, your license will *only* work for the appropriate version, so please choose the ISO carefully. The installation must be activated within 30 days as usual or it will expire.

  Please see [**this post** for the official links to the Windows 7 SP1 ISOs](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/)

Comment: This will work.  Use the ISOs from DigitalRiver, the keys from MSDN/MSDNAA/Dreamspark that require the SDM will still work for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using wine ( wine-1.4.1_1,1 ):

/* you may want to use a new wine prefix */

1. `winetricks ie6`
2. overwrite `$WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/iexplore.exe` with the new installed `IEXPLORE.EXE` in `Programs\ Files /Internet\ Explore/` 
   /* this is a work around to change the default ie, I'm sure there is cleaner way but I put no more than 2 seconds of thought */
3. get the `.msi`, not `.pkg`!! ( under wine the smart link will forward you the `.msi` )
4. install the msi via `msiexec`
5. run the `sdm` binary ( which will use the new `ie6` /* default ie */ ) with the `*.sdx` as a command line argument

Comment: This will not work, the SDM binary doesn't run even if these steps are done.  I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that this trick works.

The sdm binary is located in `~/.wine/drive_c/users/"your_login"/Local Settings/Application Data/e-academy Inc/SecureDownloadManager` and is named `SecureDownloadManager.exe`.

Launch it like this: `wine SecureDownloadManager.exe file.sdx` and a browser window will appear, just click on the Donwload button to download the ISO image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe izx's answer is better for Windows 7, but if you want to open and download any .sdx file  with the **recent SDM** in Ubuntu, you need the following steps and commands:

- Download your .sdx file with your browser.

  ```
  apt-get install wine
  apt-get install winetricks
  wget e5.onthehub.com/Static/Installers/SDM_EN.msi
  wine msiexec /i SDM_EN.msi
  ```
- Choose directory C:\SDM\ during installation for easier path to it.

  ```
  export WINEARCH=win32
  export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32
  winetricks ie6
  ```
- I am not sure if IE6 is needed, but I have installed it anyway. Maybe IE8 is enough though.

  ```
  winetricks msxml3
  winetricks ie8
  ```

And finally:

```
    wine ../.wine/drive_c/SDM/e-academy\ Inc/SecureDownloadManager/SecureDownloadManager.exe myfile.sdx
```

Good luck!

Source: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30731

Answer (score 0):

You do not need wine. Someone reverse engineered SDM and ported a repo to github.

[xSDM](https://github.com/v3l0c1r4pt0r/xSDM)

The git manual gives most details, and provides a link to his site that gives comprehensive instructions. I have successfully used it to download Windows Server 2012 R2 from my DreamSpark student account while using Trusty Tahr.

*Note: The large file sizes of most everything on DreamSpark mean attempting this on a 32bit distro is a fruitless endeavour. Your host machine will most likely need x64 architecture.*

Answer (score -1):

The .pkg file is for Macs. The site sees you're not using windows and redirects you.
If you trick it to think you're using Windows, e.g. by using Internet Explorer via wine or the ["user-agent switcher" add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) you should be able to download a .msi file which wine will be able to run.

[TL;DR: Here's a DL link](http://e5.onthehub.com/Static/Installers/SDM_DE.msi)

P.S: If IE doesn't propely download, just copy the link over to your regular browser ;)